# What can we deduce about $R$ in this graph of $I$ against $V$, where $R = \frac{V}{I}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, graphing-functions, mathematical-physics

Why is **D** the correct answer to the multiple-choice question below?

*For a reader unfamiliar with physics, the only physics one needs to know is that the resistance of a component is given as $R = \frac{V}{I}$.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: The correct answer most be C or D because of the formula that is given $R = V / I$. Now the question is just which of the two
$$
\frac{V_1}{I_1} \quad\text{ and }\quad \frac{V_2}{I_2}
$$
is greatest.

Since the curve passes through the origin for any point $(V,I)$ on the curve the quantity $\frac{I}{V}$ gives the slope of the line that passes through the origin and the point $(V,I)$. It is clear then from the graph that
$$
\frac{I_2}{V_2} > \frac{I_1}{V_1}.
$$
That means
$$
R_2 = \frac{V_2}{I_2} > \frac{V_1}{I_1} = R_2.
$$

Comment: why does it matter that the curve is passing through the origin?

Comment: @hb20007: (It doesn't). It just makes it easier to estimate the slopes of the lines. What is really important is that you have a curve that is increasing and concave upward.

Comment: From what I got from your answer, finding $I \over V$ is equivalent to drawing a tangent line and finding its gradient. Is that correct? If not, why doesn't that method work to find $R$?

Comment: @hb20007: I am not sure that I understand your confusion. Remember that $R$ is equal to $V$ divided by $I$. The slopes that you find are $I$ divided by $V$ (so the other way around). Remember also that the slope of a line that passes through two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $(y_2 - y_1) / (x_2 - x_1)$. And if one of the points is the origin (say $(x_1, y_1) = (0,0)$), then the slope is just $y_2 / x_2$.

Comment: I see. So if I draw a tangent line at $V_2$ it should pass through the origin?

Comment: @hb20007: If you draw a line through the origin and the point $(V_2, I_2)$, then you get the slope $V_2 / I_2$. And if you do the same thing for the other point, then you can see that $V_2 / I_2 > V_1 / I_1$.

Comment: Yes this is where my confusion lies... How does a line through the origin and the point $(V_2,I_2)$, give us the slope $V_2/I_2$? I thought the slope $V_2/I_2$ would be given by a line that is tangential to ($V_2,I_2$) which would actually not pass through the origin

Comment: @hb20007: Do you know how to find the slope of the line that passes through two given points? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form)

Comment: It turns out we are talking about different things. You are talking about using a line from the origin to each point to find out which is increasing more, while I am talking about drawing a tangent line through the point $V_2$ and then finding its gradient and then finding the inverse of that gradient to get $R$. I believe the tangent method is wrong and doesn't actually give $R$ as it gives a different answer. Do you know why it's wrong?

Comment: @hb20007: Ok, I see what you are saying now. I had overlooked the word "tangent". Sorry. The slope of the tangent says something about how fast $I$ is increasing when $V$ is increasing. The slope of the tangent isn't related to $R$ in that it is the actually valued of $I$ and $V$ and the point in question that determines $R$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes.. I think you mean it's the actual values of I and V that give rise to R and not how they change with respect to each other. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @hb20007: That is right.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a 'rate of change' question. To get the resistance you simply need the values of V and I, as your formula suggests. To determine that the resistance is decreasing, notice that proportionally the quotient is decreasing.
Roughly $V_2$ = 1.25$V_1$ and $I_2$ = 1.5$I_1$ so $\frac{V_2}{I_2}$ = $\frac{1.25V_1}{1.5I_1}$

Comment: Does drawing a tangent at $V_2$ also work to find $R$ at that point, which would be the inverse of the gradient of the tangent?

Comment: Never-mind, I got it from Thomas' comment

Answer (score 1):

I think the assumption here is that resistance is defined in terms of Ohm's law; that is, the component's resistance changes depending on $V$ so that Ohm's law still holds. This means that $R = \frac{V_2}{I_2}$ simply by definition, and since $\frac{V_1}{I_1} > \frac{V_2}{I_2}$, resistance decreases from $V_1$ to $V_2$.

Differentiating the function with respect to $V$ and taking the reciprocal gives the correct answer if the component is purely Ohmic ($I = V/R$ for constant $R$), but in the case of a non-linear function, say $I = V^2$, you will get $\frac{dI}{dV} = 2V$ so that $\frac{V}{I} = \frac{1}{V} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{dI}{dV}} = \frac{1}{2V}$.

Answer (score 1):

V=IR(note: here, R is a variable, for, the relation between V,I does not give a straight-line)

or, dV=R(dI)+I(dR)

or, (dI/dV)=(1/R)(1-I(dR/dV))

(dI/dV) is the slope of the curve

solving this differential-equation, we get V=IR, because we have merely retraced our path back
to the starting-point.

R=V/I

so, at V=V2,I=I2, we have R=V2/I2

similarly, at V=V1,I=I1, we have R=V1/I1

from rough-sketch, you can view that (dI/dV)>0

now, (dI/dV)=(1/R)(1-I(dR/dV))

so, 1-I(dR/dV)>0 or, 1+(I/dV)(-dR)

this is possible, if dR<0, because, then -dR>0, as I,dV are positive

so, resistance decreases.